# Is it possible to change form data before sending it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'd like to find any generic method to change data before sending forms. It is, if I have a `<form>` that contains a `<input>` of certain type (class) and user press *send* button, I'd like to transform this input value to another format so it arrive to server in a corrected format.

I know I can set a *submit()* handler to process data, but I need a generic solution that setup this mechanism on load on all page forms and forgets about it (perhaps some forms are sent by AJAX, other use Jquery.validate to send, etc)

Answer (score 7):

Use jQuery's to select all form elements: `$('form')` and register a handler for the form `submit` event. Something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var $this = $(this)
    var formData = $this.serialize()
    // do some thing to it
    var yourData = transform(formData)
    $.ajax({
       post: $this.attr('action'),
       data: yourData,
       ...
    })
})
```

#### References

- [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- [jQuery CSS Selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- [Form serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: This is what I had in mind... for ajax forms add your transfomr manually since thats what youre doing with an ajax form anyway, manually.

Comment: This does not (yet) show the reply (or do the redirect).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("submit",function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var field = form.find("input[name=first_name]");
    if (field.length()>0) field.val(field.val().replace("a","b")); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Problem with this is that Jquery.validate() puts an error message if 'b' is not a valid input and stops form submission.

Comment: But that is up to you to make sure it is.

Comment: It depends.. For example, for a spanish user the date "25/5/2010" is ok, so it must be valid for jquery.validate but if I change to "5/25/2010" before jquery.validate read the input content, it will produce an error :(

Answer (score -2):

Yes, why not?

Have an onclick on the form submit button and there you can do whatever you like before you invoke submit(). To add a same function to all input type submit, then iterate over all input elements with the type=buttons and add your onclick handler function to it.

All your forms need to be of the same kind, or if some use input type=submit while others use a button element with your own javascript then you will have to adjust for that.

Comment: An onclick() handler won't catch everything - many people submit forms without clicking on the 'done!' button.

Comment: my bad, he should decorate the submit function.