# javascript unset posted array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, unset

After submitting a form i need to unset the posted values, based on other values, before actually parsing the posted data to php.

For example: 
My form contains 2 hidden fields and 2 regular inputs:

```
<form class='myForm'>
<input type="hidden" name="hide[0]" id="h[0]" value="someValue1" data-key="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="hide[1]" id="h[1]" value="someValue2" data-key="1" />
<input type=“text” name=“text[0]” id=“t[0]” value="" data-key=“0” />
<input type=“text” name=“text[1]” id=“t[1]” value="" data-key="1" />
<input type=“submit” value=“submit” />
</form>
```

i'm trying to unset posted value via javascript:

$('.myForm').submit(function() {
// loop through each input type = text

```
$('.myForm').submit(function() {
    // loop through each input type = text
    $(':input[type=text]').each(function() {
        var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
        var textValue = $(this).val();

        if (textValue < 1) {
            // unset posted input [type=text] with data-key 
            // unset posted hidden with same data-key 
        }

    });
});
```

Unfortunately i have no clue how to unset the posted values without removing the actual form elements.
Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Do you need to "reset" the form values or do you need to modify the values you are sending to your backend?

Comment: What do you mean by 'posted values'? When values get 'posted' they get send to the web server. If you want to modify the data before posting them do the server, you need to use javscript to prevent the default behavior of form posting. Modify the dataset, and then post it manually to the server. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730625/is-it-possible-to-change-form-data-before-sending-it